# Query on App.config and AppName.exe.config - C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've built a console application in C# where I've stored the Folder paths in App.config file. I tried to change the Folder paths in App.config file, the changes are not getting reflected when I am running the .exe in Debug folder.

But when I am making the same changes in AppName.exe.config file in Debug folder, the changes are getting reflected on Running .exe

So can you please guide me how to build the code to reflect the changes when made in App.config file itself.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click **app.config** > **Properties** > **Copy to output directory** > **Copy if newer**

Comment: Yeah..but I will have two app.config files in total. One in the debug folder and other outside.

Comment: You will have one in your VS solution and that's the one you should change. When you run Debug session the one in your solution will get copied every time to \bin\Debug overwriting the existing one.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.